# WCF Service Throttling

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soa, throttling

Lets assume that I'm dealing with a service that involves sending large amounts of data.

If I implement this with WCF, will WCF throttle the service based on how much memory each request takes to serve? Or will I be getting continuous out of memory exceptions each time I receive a large number of hits to my service?

I'm quite curious as to dealing with this problem outside of WCF, I'm still a bit new to service development...

Comment: Any .NET application can generate an OutOfMemory exception.  I would love too see smart execution hosts some day, but it seems like that would require another layer of communication between the application and the host.  If it was worth it, it would likely already exist for Windows Services.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While using the binding attributes and readerQuotas like Andrew Hare suggests will allow for essentially an unlimited size for most practical uses, keep in mind that the you will run into other issues such as timeouts if you accept a long running command, no matter how that service is constructed (using WCF or not).

No matter what the size of your message is, the WCF service will need to be throttled for performance so that it is not flooded.  If you are hosting it in IIS or WAS, you will have additional built-in features to those hosting environments that will make your service much more "highly available".  However, you still need to pay attention to concurrency issues.  The following WCF config provides an example of setting some throttling values.

```
   <system.serviceModel>

    ...

     <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="GenericServiceBehavior">
           <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:09:10"/>
           <serviceThrottling
             maxConcurrentCalls="20"
             maxConcurrentSessions="20"
             maxConcurrentInstances="20"
           />
         </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Exactly what I"m after.  I imagine that we will go through a tuning phase after lowering the memory usage per call as much as possible :).

Excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

WCF does have a default payload size limit that will reject messages over a certain number of bytes.  This is configurable of course in the binding section of your configuration file.  Here is a crude example with a [`basicHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) showing you many of the attributes available to you:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="testBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas
              maxDepth="2147483647"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

The idea is that you can create many different bindings that you can use for different scenarios.  This is nice as you can fine tune how your services are consumed and only increase the message size limit for the endpoints that need them.

Comment: I understand what your getting at, but if I were able to control the size of messages I would.  Gotta love images.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using NetTCPBinding or NetNamedPipeBinding you can use the MaxConnections property:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="myTCPBinding" maxConnections="15"/>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: This is applicable to me, so +1, but EnocnRoll's answer was very clear.  Maybe next time :(.

Comment: Yup - I was just extending his answer a bit.  :)