# What is the message queue size for a Windows hosted service?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf

I can see MaxConcurrentCalls and service ServiceThrottlingBehavior. What is the message queue size of a Windows hosted service? (WCF)

Where can I see this setting in Windows? Is it based on number of processor cores?

For IIS hosted services, there is a queue count of 1000 configurable  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/557047a3-a77d-4e3e-833c-ab4b6f9d40b8/wcf-queue-behavior-for-maxconcurrentcalls?forum=wcf
Where can I find the limit in windows hosted services??? and what's the limit?

Comment: Looks like what you're looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480020/wcf-service-throttling)

Comment: for IIS hosted services, there is queue count of 1000 configurable  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/557047a3-a77d-4e3e-833c-ab4b6f9d40b8/wcf-queue-behavior-for-maxconcurrentcalls?forum=wcf     Where can I find the limit in windows hosted services??? and what's the limit?